# Template dataflow: how to get current_date

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam, dataflow

I made dataflow code that writes a pcollection in Bigquery. In one of the BG columns I am writing the current_date related to the execution date.

Everything works fine when executing the code in dataflow, but I have an issue while executing the code as a Template:
It seems that current_date is taking the date on which I transformed the code into a template.
For example:
If I transform the code into a template on 01/02/2021 and execute it on 05/01/2021, the date that will be written in Bigquery is 01/02/2021.

Could you help me find a way to get the execution date when running the template?

I have been struggling for a few days now.

Comment: Can you share how to you generate the current date in your template?

Comment: Please share a snippet of your template code, specifically where you're getting the current date.